# Visual Basic data set not updating with mdb file

Tags: vb.net, vba, ms-access

I have a .mdb (Access) file that I am using in my VB program. The program is basically just querying out data from the file. I prefer to update the database through access and then my vb program will just automatically be up to date upon saving the .mdb file. I have a data connection connected to the .mdb file and using the data set on my form. For some reason when I update the .mdb file, the program will not be updated with the new items....even if I right click and refresh the data connection and data set. 
Is there a way I can fix this so that when I wont have to worry about deleting the connections and resaving in VB and creating an executable. I'd prefer my end result to just always work upon the .mdb file being updated.

Answer (score 0):

When adding the connection and dataset there is a part that prompts you about it being a local file and if you want, you can have a copy saved to the projects directory. Clicking no will make sure that the local file will be used and not the copy in the project folder.